# como quitar el cuadrito que aparece al pasar el mouse sobre una imagen insertada en HTML?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se como quitar ese cuadrito que aparece al pasar el mouse sobre las imágenes.

Comment: Eso es algo de los navegadores si no me equivoco... Así que dudo que se pueda deshabilitar a nivel de programación de la web, pero desde el navegador propio, si se puede deshabilitar. No estoy 100% seguro de esto, pero es lo que creo.

Comment: gracias Gabriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta usar: `pointer-events: none;` para la imagen.

[Aquí](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2345) hay más información al respecto, dice que es una solución a corto plazo, ya que también quita el alt-text, pero eso solo microsoft lo puede solucionar a largo plazo,

Comment: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/2345                              Aquí hay más información al respecto, dice que es una solución a corto plazo, ya que también quita el alt-text, pero eso solo microsoft lo puede solucionar a largo plazo, saludos!